# Why ":" in key value pair converted to = while printing it in console.

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array of objects like

```
var data = [{id:1,name:"pqr"},{id:2,name:"lmn"},{id:3,name:"xyz"}]
```

when I console log, it display as follow,

```
[Object { id=1,  name="pqr"}, Object { id=2,  name="lmn"}, Object { id=3,  name="xyz"}]
```

Why?

Comment: Its upto the implementations to decide how the objects have to be printed on console. The language specification doesn't specify any specific rules about this I guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's shown in the console isn't JavaScript code, so it can be in any format the authors of the console want it to be. And that varies from implementation to implementation, and even varies *within* an implementation sometimes based on whether the console was open or closed when you logged the object. (Yes, really — Chrome's console behaves differently based on whether it was open or closed at the time.)

Here's an example from Chrome when the console was open;

[image]

And if I expand that:

[image]

Vs. when **closed** when the log occurred:

[image]

And when I expand that:

[image]

But Firebug's console in Firefox looks different:

[image]

As does Firefox's **own** console (rather than Firebug); the part on the right appeared when I clicked the word "Array":

[image]